# Segmentation fault when using `curses` in Python on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, python, segmentation-fault, ncurses

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 (directly, skipping intermediary versions). Since the upgrade python is Segfaulting when I try to use the `curses` module. This happens in both Python versions that are installed by default:

2.7:

```
mst@mst-nb1:~$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import curses
>>> curses.wrapper(lambda x: x)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

3.6:

```
mst@mst-nb1:~$ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import curses
>>> curses.wrapper(lambda x: x)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html).

Comment: I would not fill a bug report before trying that in a clean 18.04. The official upgrade path procedure is not skipping versions. You could have some component that is corrupted.

Comment: @IporSircer Do you even understand the amount of information a bug investigation can involve? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467199/mousepad-not-working-in-lenovo-thinkpad/467200#467200